# How do I create a Docker container with strictatime set on the root filesystem?

Tags: docker

I am trying to see what files a program in a Docker container uses by seeing what atimes change on the files before and after I run a command. However, by default the Docker container seems to launch with relatime set as a mount option, and I'm having trouble finding a way to enable strictatime instead.

I tried using --cap-add sys_ptrace and use strace to see what files are accessed but unfortunately it was too slow and created some instability in the program I was attempting to trace.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you found a solution ? I'm facing the same issue :(